# Count codepoints in a string in Elixir

Tags: unicode, elixir, string-length, codepoint

The [`String.length/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html#length/1) function returns the number of *graphemes* in a UTF-8 binary.

If I want to know how many Unicode *codepoints* are in the string, I know I can do:

```elixir
string |> String.codepoints |> length
```

But this produces an unnecessary intermediate list of all the codepoints and iterates the characters twice. Is there a way I can calculate the codepoints directly, without producing the intermediate list?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [comprehension](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#for/1) with a bitstring generator and the [`reduce`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.SpecialForms.html#for/1-the-reduce-option) option to count the codepoints without building up the intermediate list.

```elixir
for <<_::utf8 <- string>>, reduce: 0, do: (count -> count + 1)
```

Example:

```elixir
iex> string = "‍♂️"
iex> for <<_::utf8 <- string>>, reduce: 0, do: (count -> count + 1)
5
iex> string |> String.codepoints |> length
5
iex> String.length(string)
1
```

This has the added bonus that it also works with UTF-16 and UTF-32 strings, if you replace `utf8` with `utf16` or `utf32`:

```elixir
iex> utf8_string = "I'm going to be UTF-16!"
"I'm going to be UTF-16!"
iex> utf16_string = :unicode.characters_to_binary(utf8_string, :utf8, :utf16)
<<0, 73, 0, 39, 0, 109, 0, 32, 0, 103, 0, 111, 0, 105, 0, 110, 0, 103, 0, 32, 0,
  116, 0, 111, 0, 32, 0, 98, 0, 101, 0, 32, 0, 85, 0, 84, 0, 70, 0, 45, 0, 49,
  0, 54, 0, 33>>
iex> for <<_::utf8 <- utf8_string>>, reduce: 0, do: (count -> count + 1)
23
iex> for <<_::utf16 <- utf16_string>>, reduce: 0, do: (count -> count + 1)
23
```

Comment: I ran a benchmark between the two, and using your comprehension is 85% faster than calling `Kernel.length/1`

Comment: @vinibrsl good idea. But I couldn't reproduce your results. How did you benchmark? I just ran one, and in my results `to_charlist` was actually faster and used less memory than the comprehension, but there wasn't much in it. Perhaps I need to update this answer...  https://gist.github.com/adamu/911b3754736f1c584e45222ba9a4c107

Comment: https://gist.github.com/vinibrsl/707a4a64737fab8b6a19f4620d8fd47a

Comment: Ah, longer string  Results in my script for that string: `charlist 107.57 μs, comprehension 256.59 μs - 2.39x slower, codepoints  725.87 μs - 6.75x slower`. So it seems while the comprehension is faster that `codepoints`, `to_charlist` is even faster (and uses less memory). Not sure why? I'll revisit this when I have time.

Comment: @vinibrsl actually even for your script, I get `Codepoints took 0.6852230000000012 seconds
Comprehension took 0.24642800000000145 seconds`. So something's up with your setup, maybe?